# Bigfloat - Error in the precision

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point, bigfloat

I'm trying to use Bigfloat library in python 2.7.

```
from bigfloat import *

f1 = Context(precision=2000)

with precision(2000):  f1 = 1e-19*1e-19*9e9/((1-1e-18)*(1-1e-18))-1e-19*1e-19*9e9

with precision(100):  f2 = 1.6e-27*1.6e-27*6.6e-11/(1e-18*1e-18)

print BigFloat(f1) print f2
```

Python gives me `f1=0`, but it is not true. I tested it with g++ and the result is `1.75e-46`.

Is it an error in my program? Is it not possible to calculate this precision with Bigfloat ? Is it an error in the lib?

Comment: You are using normal floats, not the ones implemented by the bigfloat library.

Comment: How can I do for that ? I don't find an example for create a variable with BigFloat.

Comment: You need to create the BigFloat instances before doing the calculation, not after. `1e-19*1e-19` is a multiplication of two normal floats rather than bigfloats. I haven't used this library so I don't know the exact usage.

Comment: I suggest using `gmpy2` rather than `bigfloat`.  `bigfloat` isn't well maintained.

Comment: Rather than using a high-precision floating-point library, you might be better off rearranging the expression for `f1` to reduce the rounding error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example, here's how you might compute `f1` to a precision of 256 bits using the `bigfloat` library.

```
>>> from bigfloat import BigFloat, precision
>>> with precision(256):
...     x = BigFloat('1e-19')
...     y = BigFloat('9e9')
...     z = BigFloat('1e-18')
...     f1 = x * x * y / ((1 - z) * (1 - z)) - x * x * y
... 
>>> f1
BigFloat.exact('1.800000000000000002700000000000000003600000000000000004500006811997284879750608e-46', precision=256)
```

Note the use of `BigFloat('1e-19')`, which is creating the closest binary float to `10**-19` at the current precision (256 bits). This is different from `BigFloat(1e-19)` (without the single quotes), since there `1e-19` is a Python float, so has already been rounded to 53-bit precision.

Take a look at the [documentation](http://bigfloat.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/index.html#bigfloat-construction) for more details.

However, with a bit of creativity and algebra, you don't need a high-precision library at all here. You can rewrite the expression for `f1` as:

```
f1 = x * x * y * (1 / ((1 - z) * (1 - z)) - 1)
```

and by putting everything over a common denominator, the quantity in parentheses can be rewritten as `(2 - z) * z / ((1 - z) * (1 - z))`.  So you could equally well compute `f1` as:

```
f1 = x * x * y * (2-z) * z / ((1 - z) * (1 - z))
```

and in this form, you don't lose accuracy when `z` is very small.  So now regular Python floats are good enough:

```
>>> x = 1e-19
>>> y = 9e9
>>> z = 1e-18
>>> f1 = x * x * y * (2 - z) * z / ((1 - z) * (1 - z))
>>> f1
1.8e-46
```

If you do decide you want to use a high-precision floating-point library, I'd also recommend looking at the [gmpy2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gmpy2) library.  It's based on the same underlying MPFR library as bigfloat, but it's better maintained.